# I have enabled IpV6 only. Why I can still ping 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, ipv6

I would like to test few scenarios on IpV6 stack. For that reason I have disabled IpV4 stack for each network adapter in network adapter settings (Windows 10).

Now, when I run `ping 127.0.0.1` - I still do get answer from ICMP. My question is - why this happens and how can I avoid this?

**UPD**: I might have found one reason for this. Running `netsh interface ip show addresses` shows special interface... `Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1`. Guess this is the reason. Now I wonder is it installed by default in IPV6 only and can it be removed.

Comment: IPv6 is to a degree backwards compatible to IPv4. This might be the reason. The entire IPv4 address range is mapped into IPv6 as special address range.

Comment: Thanks, will look through IpV6 standard to verify that, didn't know that

Comment: It's `::FFFF:0.0.0.0` to `::FFFF:255.255.255.255` (IPv4 notation in IPv6) or `::FFFF:0:0` to `::FFFF:FFFF:FFFF` (default IPv6 notation)

Comment: Those are internal ranges. But I am still not sure which part of protocol or OS does resolve 127.0.0.1 to local machine when IpV4 is disabled...

Comment: This depends on the OS. Windows is usually trying to be backwards compatible. A more general definition may be found here [RFC4038](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4038), see chapter 4.

Comment: linux usually first looks into /etc/hosts like windows have this file too. Enabling ipv6 does not mean that ipv4 is disabled. does `ping ::1` wotks for you?

Comment: Yes, ping ::1 works for me, ``ping localhost`` resolves to ::1, and ``ping [real ip v6]`` works while ``ping [host's ip v4]`` doesn't... But ping 127.0.0.1 still works. I'm OK with that, just not sure whethe I have disabled IpV4 completely...

Comment: As far s I remember the loopback adapter which handles 127.0.0.1 is not visible in the network list so you have not reconfigured it, so it still has IPVv4 enabled. And not the loopback adapter can not be removed because Windows requires localhost connection, otherwise the whole system would not be able to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is to disable IPv4 *binding* on interfaces that you can see.
You have not really disabled IPv4 in the system, and doing so might (for a while) not be a good idea and not supported.

As you noticed, you have a loopback interface, which is where 127.0.0.1 and ::1 is assigned.
If you really want to you could try to uninstall IPv4 protocol. But be prepared for a broken system.

Some mention ::ffff:127.0.0.1 it is true that IPv4 can be represented by this IPv6 address, it is just a representation in IPv6 of IPv4, the actual protocol used here (if policy is correct) is still IPv4.

In regards to localhost that is the named representation of the IPs, which is not really relevant. Which is used depends on routing policy.